# Having trouble storing a date and time in a DATETIME column. (Using PHP and MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling a date and time from a text box in this format: yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss

And I am trying to store this in my MySQL column set to store "DATETIME" strings. When I execute the query, the data in the table is "0000-00-00 00:00:00". I can print the string to the browser before sending it off to the SQL server and it is formatted correctly. I know I have to be missing something stupid. Why isn't my string being stored correctly on the table?

My apologies. My first time asking a coding question on a forum. haha. Here is my current code (stripped down to the basics):

```
    $start = "2011-24-07 18:00:00";
    $end = "2011-24-07 21:00:00";
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO table (start, end) VALUES ('$start','$end')";
```

Comment: it will be very difficult to guess if you don't post the code

Comment: Do you have the code snippet where you are building the `INSERT` statement?  My first guess would be that you are not quoting the date string.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is, your date format is not correct. Print your $sql query as well on page to debug it. Then copy that query and run in mysql server. You will get exact error where the mistake is.

```
2011-24-07 should be 2011-07-24 :)
```

Comment: Sorry for wasting everyone's time. I had swapped the month and day in my time format. Thanks for your kindness!

Comment: Just a tip for remembering date format, it's always in decreasing order of unit magnitude, I.e. Year > month > day > hour etc.